# Getchar storing unneccesary information

Tags: c++, getchar

I'm having trouble to understand why the following code does not work properly. It's just an example, program supposed to take some ints from user until he/she presses dot ('.') and than print out ints which were greater than 3.

The trouble I'm having is that everytime I press dot, the final output contains this dot, which makes me wonder whether buffer is holding something or maybe I messed up with something in my code.

Would you be so kind and help me out with this, so that the final output won't contain the dot ? (:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std; 

bool greaterThan(int n)
{
   return n>3;  
}

int main(void)
{
   vector<int> vs; 
   int n, c;  

do{
    cout << "Enter the number: "; 
    cin >> n; 
    vs.push_back(n); 
    c=getchar(); 
    putchar(c); 
}while(c!='.'); 



vector<int>::iterator funkyIterator = find_if(vs.begin(), vs.end(), greaterThan); 

while(funkyIterator != vs.end())
{
  cout << *funkyIterator << " "; 
  funkyIterator = find_if(funkyIterator +1, vs.end(), greaterThan); 
}

}
```

Anything that is particularly wrong with my code ? 
I supposed I could just add some condition so that the c can't equal to '.' but actually it doesn't make any sense at all since the do while loop will last forever.

Comment: Each time you call `getchar`, you also call `putchar`. The input contains a dot. Why do you think the output shouldn't?

Comment: So how can I get rid of it ? Move putchar to different line or what ?

Comment: Also don't use both C and C++ I/O calls.

Comment: You should not be calling `getchar` at all, or `#include <stdio.h>` for that matter. C++ has `std::istream::get`.

Comment: You are also causing formatting failure on `cin` by entering a dot where a number is expected, and then pushing the invalid "result" of the input operation to the vector.

Comment: @n.m. do you mean like remove the entire line with: c=getchar(); ? I did it and as the result I can't stop the loop...

Comment: It's not homework, I really cannot understand the reason why do you bother to reply to this topic, since plainly you're not keen to help and your advices aren't helpfull at all.